# Phantom unread message in Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, macos

I have a smart mailbox with only one rule: messages that are unread.
Right now I have no unread messages in any of my acccounts, yet the smart mailbox shows a counter of 1.
Opening the smart mailbox shows no messages (this is correct). If a new message arrives, the counter goes up to 2, then as soon as I read that message it goes back to 1.
I tried:

- Rebuilding my inboxes
- Rebuilding my smart mailbox. Logs this error:

> 27/10/13 11:42:18,753 Mail[16057]: *** Assertion failure in
>   +[MFLibrary mailboxIDForMailbox:loadIfNotPresent:], /SourceCache/Mail/Mail-1816/FrameworkTargets/MailFramework/Library/MFLibrary.m:9814
>   Called on smart mailbox Unread (  0   MailCore
>   0x00007fff8c6ecc8c -[MCAssertionHandler
>   _handleFailureWithPreamble:description:arguments:] + 141  1   MailCore                            0x00007fff8c6ecafd -[MCAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 215  2
>   Mail                                0x00007fff8cdf105d +[MFLibrary
>   mailboxIDForMailbox:loadIfNotPresent:] + 170  3   Mail
>   0x00007fff8ce0ea24 -[MFLibraryStore
>   *rebuildTableOfContentsSynchronously] + 533   4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff921f3dec **invoking*** + 140  5   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff921f3c54 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 308   6   MailCore
>   0x00007fff8c73db74 -[MCMonitoredInvocation invoke] + 211  7   MailCore
>   0x00007fff8c760808 -[MCThrowingInvocationOperation main] + 40     8
>   MailCore                            0x00007fff8c704f08
>   -[*MCInvocationOperation main] + 332  9   Foundation                          0x00007fff86da9591 -[*_NSOperationInternal _start:] + 631   10 
>   Foundation                          0x00007fff86da923b
>   __NSOQSchedule_f + 64     11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8f3212ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8     12  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x00007fff8f3257ff _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 154  13 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8f3212ad
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8  14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8f32309e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326     15 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8f324193
>   _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40     16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff8c3dfef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314  17 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff8c3e2fb9 start_wqthread
>   + 13 )

- Deleting and recreating my smart mailbox
- Adding a rule restricting the smart mailbox to one account (if the rule is added, it works correctly)
- Relaunching mail, rebooting
- Looking in the logs. Only line from mail: `27/10/13 11:38:19,956 Mail[1174]: View Based NSTableView error: preparedCellAtColumn:row: was called. Please log a bug with the backtrace from this log, or stop using the method.`

I'm kinda out of ideas. Is there anything else I can try, any debug info I can access?

Comment: Please use code formatting for Terminal output! Quote formatting doesn't preserve line breaks and is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed this for my smart mailboxes (Mail.app v7.0 1822) by following these steps:

1. Open a terminal
2. Re-index Spotlight

   sudo mdutil -E /

I suspect this is related to Mavericks improvements in Spotlight, as it now indexes Mail.app messages much better than in previous releases.

Comment: marking this as correct, but didn't try. My mail somehow fixed itself, it's possible that Spotlight decided to reindex (it often does)

Comment: This has worked great both times I ran into this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately these answers age pretty quickly (I'm not sure if this works anymore in Yosemite)

Comment: Searched for a solution to the same problem. On Mac OS Sierra and this solved my issue even now. The most frustrating bug I've come across to date in Mac OS. Cheers for the quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

Vacumming the sqlite index may also be worth a try:

```
$ sqlite3 ~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Envelope\ Index vacuum;
```